# angle of inscribed triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, gre-exam

let us consider following problem:

we have inscribed  triangle,like this

[image]

we are asked  to determine if given $x$ is  acute or obtuse,$O$ is center of circle,as i know if  $CB$ would be  diameter,then $x$ would be  $90$,or $CAB$ would be right triangle,but  in this case  what it should be?if i trust  diagram then maybe it seems that  it is  more then $90$,but because GRE said that dont trust diagram,then  what i should know about it?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but how do you show that $CAB$ is greater than $DAE$? It seems like you are resorting to the diagram again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a proposition that says that if you connect $C$ to $O$ and $B$ to $O$, then the reflex $\angle BOC$ is twice of $\angle BAC$. And since reflex $\angle BOC >180^{\circ}$, we are done.

To argue that the reflex $\angle BOC >180^{\circ}$, we can just say that the usual $\angle BOC <180^{\circ}$, because it is contained in the triangle $BOC$.

See: http://www.mathopenref.com/arccentralangletheorem.html (The prop will be a corollary of that.)

Comment: sorry $BOC$ is more then $180$?

Comment: @dato Yes! Read carefully I said the REFLEX. :)

Comment: i still did not understand sorry

Comment: There are two angles when two lines meet at a point. Usually, what we call the "angle" is the inside angle, ie angle which is less than $180$. The reflex angle is the one which is greater than $180$.

Comment: you mean angle which is not in $BOC$ triangle?

Comment: Yup! But the central angle theorem still holds! :)

Comment: but here http://www.mathopenref.com/arccentralangletheorem.html reflect angle is  $280$ right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9857/discussion-between-yanbo-and-dato)